# Download PDF files from webpage

Tags: vb.net, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to download files from website. My current solution seems to work but there are some things I don't understand.

First issue comes while:

```
//div[@class='large-4 medium-4 columns']//a
```

There are other divs with class `large-4 medium-4 columns`. So I am getting couple of unnecessary links. How to get rid of them? I need only pages that contain `/products/`

Second issue is that nothing gets downloaded to `C:\temp\` and I guess there is something with:

```
//div[@class='large-6 medium-8 columns large-centered']/a[string-length(@href)>0]
```

but what is wrong?

"xxx" is the link in my code and it should be

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim mainUrl As String = "xxx"
        Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(mainUrl) '< - - - Load the webage into htmldocument

        Dim listLinks As New List(Of String)

        Dim srcs As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='large-4 medium-4 columns']//a") '< - - - select nodes with links
        For Each src As HtmlNode In srcs

            ' Store links in array
            listLinks.Add(src.Attributes("href").Value)

            Console.WriteLine(src.Attributes("href").Value)

        Next

        Console.Read()

        For Each productLink As String In listLinks
            Dim prodDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(productLink)

            Dim scrapedsrcs As HtmlNodeCollection = prodDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='large-6 medium-8 columns large-centered']/a[string-length(@href)>0]") '< - - - select nodes with links

            If scrapedsrcs IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each scrapedlink As HtmlNode In scrapedsrcs
                    ' Show links in console
                    'Console.WriteLine($"-- {scrapedlink.Attributes("href").Value}") '< - - - Print urls  

                    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(scrapedlink.Attributes("href").Value, "C:\temp\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(scrapedlink.Attributes("href").Value) & ".pdf")
                Next
            End If
        Next

        Console.Read()

        ' End of scraping

    End Sub

End Module
```

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, first one should be

```
//div[@class='row inset1 productItem padb1 padt1']/div[@class='large-4 medium-4 columns']//a
```

Comment: The error comes from you not understanding how to select the path, the product name is "large-4 medium-4 columns" but is also a part of "row inset1 productItem padb1 padt1" just like a house is a part of a street (or city, or a country, or planet...). So instead of just specifying that you want houses, specify something more along that. For example, this looks like quick and easy filter to use https://i.imgur.com/x0Yg1iH.png

Comment: Ok, now I understand. So it should be `//div[@class='row inset1 productItem padb1 padt1']/div[@class='large-4 medium-4 columns']//a`

Comment: Look at this: /html/body/div[something6]/div[something2]/div[something1]/a is the full path of one product, now, you could get it by doing html//a but with a lot of other junk, so instead of doing that, you specify something closer.

Comment: Also, if those paths were folders, / would mean "just this folder" // would mean "this folder and it's subfolders".

Comment: Yes, now I get all the needed links as they should be. However pdf link does not seem to work. Something is still wrong in this `//div[@class='row padt6 padb4']/div[@class='large-6 medium-8 columns large-centered']/a[string-length(@href)>0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will download brochures to folder where app is run:

```
    Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load("https://webpage.com")
    Dim ProductListPage As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='productContain padb6']//div[@class='large-4 medium-4 columns']/a")
    For Each src As HtmlNode In ProductListPage
        htmlDoc = New HtmlWeb().Load(src.Attributes("href").Value)
        Dim LinkTester As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='row padt6 padb4']//a")
        If LinkTester IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each dllink In LinkTester
                Dim LinkURL As String = dllink.Attributes("href").Value
                Console.WriteLine(LinkURL)

                Dim ExtractFilename As String = LinkURL.Substring(LinkURL.LastIndexOf("/"))
                Dim DLClient As New WebClient
                DLClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(LinkURL), ".\" & ExtractFilename)
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: That was a little bit shorter version... I will go to practice on other sites and try to get the real one working.

Comment: It was working fine until today, source code seems to be the same. However this is dropping an error now. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Ok, then it is maybe a reason for another question